# What is the screensize of a UIModalPresentationFullScreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, interface-builder

I have a UIModalPresentationFullScreen but my UI elements are not showing up properly. I want to define the screensize in IB, but I'm not sure what the size should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full screen is of course 1024x768 (iPad) / 480x320 (iPhone) (minus the status bar.)

Instead of defining a screen-size, you really should make the UI elements auto-resizable (use "Autosizing" in the "Size Inspector" (Cmd+3)), so your interface becomes screen-size-independent.

Comment: After setting my screensize to 1024x768, I position all of my UI elements and it looks great in IB. When I run it in the simulator, my toolbar does not seem to be aligned at the top, even tho X and Y are 0,0

Comment: @Sheehan: Make sure you reserve 20px of height for the status bar.

Comment: KennyTM - that did the trick! I set Y to 20px and everything is aligned correctly.